# Why is Docker build failing to add a specific rust version?

Tags: docker, rust, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to build a docker image from `Alpine` and add a specific version of `rust`, but I'm getting this error and the build fails.

```
#7 [3/5] RUN apk add rust=1.72.1-r0
#7 4.203 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/armv7/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#7 5.012 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/armv7/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#7 6.228 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#7 6.405   rust-1.64.0-r2:
#7 6.405     breaks: world[rust=1.72.1-r0]
#7 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c apk add rust=1.72.1-r0" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`.

```
ARG version=3.9
ARG tag=${version}-alpine3.17

FROM python:${tag} as builder
WORKDIR /app
ENV CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true

RUN apk add rust=1.72.1-r0

RUN rustc -V
```

I'm building in on a `Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v7+ #1642 SMP Mon Apr  3 17:20:52 BST 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the version of Alpine Linux that the image in question is using, you will find it is `3.17.5`:

```
docker run --rm -it python:3.9-alpine3.17 cat /etc/os-release
>>> NAME="Alpine Linux"
>>> ID=alpine
>>> VERSION_ID=3.17.5
>>> PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.17"
>>> HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
>>> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues"
```

The version of Rust that is available for that version, is [`1.64.0-r2`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=rust&branch=v3.17&repo=&arch=&maintainer=).

Comment: Updated the Alpine version according to [docker python tags](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/tags?page=1) and cross checking your link to make sure I get `Rust` version I want.  It worked!